# Sharing content with facebook sdk 4.0 + iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, share

I use the Facebook SDK on iOS (objective-c) to share an image on Facebook. Here's the code that I use:

```
-(IBAction)facebookShare:(UIButton *)sender {
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image = self.image;
photo.userGenerated = YES;
FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
content.photos = @[photo];
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];  
}
```

Where image is an UIImage that I set by picking it from the user's gallery. When I try to press my button (with this IBAction) the app crashes giving this error:

Jul  1 10:50:23 .local pkd[917]: error retrieving entitlements for pid 922
Jul  1 10:50:23 -[MainViewController sharer:didFailWithError:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd70940efd0
Jul  1 10:50:23: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MainViewController sharer:didFailWithError:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd70940efd0'

here's the new error after fixing the code in this way

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
        photo.image = //YOUR IMAGE                                                                 photo.userGenerated = YES;
        FBSDKSharePhotoContent * photoContent = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
        photoContent.photos = @[photo];
        FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
        shareDialog.shareContent = photoContent;
        shareDialog.delegate = (id)self;
        shareDialog.fromViewController = self;
        NSError * error = nil;
        BOOL validation = [shareDialog validateWithError:&error];
        if (validation) {
            [shareDialog show];
        }
```

:

ul  1 15:55:02 .local Dailypic[1169]: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:1025: Could not retrieve region info
Jul  1 15:55:06 com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.D482DFDD-3051-4759-B70D-94EC93BFF5D0.launchd_sim[471] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
Jul  1 15:55:07 o.local pkd[498]: error retrieving entitlements for pid 1169
Jul  1 15:55:07 local Dailypic[1169]: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.share Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.share error 2.)" UserInfo=0x7ffc8a59bcd0 {com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorArgumentValueKey=, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Feed share dialogs support FBSDKShareLinkContent., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorArgumentNameKey=shareContent}
Jul  1 15:55:10 local securityd[499]:  SecTaskCopyAccessGroups No keychain access group specified whilst running in simulator, falling back to default set

Finally solved using a different Emulator.

Comment: Delegate method `sharer:didFailWithError:` of `FBSDKShareDialog` is not implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a bug in the earlier version of FB SDK, but here it seems that you are missing a required implementation of a delegate methods.

```
        FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
        photo.image = //YOUR IMAGE                                                                 photo.userGenerated = YES;
        FBSDKSharePhotoContent * photoContent = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
        photoContent.photos = @[photo];
        FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
        shareDialog.shareContent = photoContent;
        shareDialog.delegate = (id)self;
        shareDialog.fromViewController = self;
        NSError * error = nil;
        BOOL validation = [shareDialog validateWithError:&error];
        if (validation) {
            [shareDialog show];
        }
```

And implement the required delegates method

```
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results {
    // handle
}
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    // handle
}
- (void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer{
    // handle
}
```

Comment: content results as undeclared identifier, and for :path is right adding _image?

Comment: Ok now the code seems good, but when I try to run it I can't get my dialog and if I "force" [shareDialog show]; the app crashes

Comment: So, Facebook App should be installed in order to upload the photo/video asset?

Comment: Hi @Andrea, Is there a way to post gifs on facebook using iOS App?

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh don't know exactly , but even if gif is not supported by FB is supported by iOS and you can convert it in JPG or PNG. If you are talking about animated GIF they are not supported by FB framework, to post them you must upload them to a specific service such as TumbIR and post their  link to FB

Comment: @Andrea Yea I was having an idea of uploading it to a server & then posting it, but I thought that you might have some knowledge to post it directly. Anyways Thanks :)