# ios swift - creating FBSDKShareDialog instance failed

Tags: ios, swift3, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying ti implement a share function use FBSDKShareKit, but when the FBSDKShareDialog cannot be created. The code is here:

```
        let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
        content.contentDescription = "Some discription"
        content.contentTitle = self.name!
        content.imageURL = self.imgURL

        let shareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
        shareDialog.shareContent = content

        shareDialog.delegate = nil
        shareDialog.fromViewController = self
        shareDialog.show()
```

when the line `let shareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()` is executed, the app just crash and throw this error message to the console:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Anybody have any idea why this happened?

Comment: Did you add bolts framework, if not then add it.

Comment: @JeckyModi Still not working.

Comment: Use only one thing, I think that might be the issue. Check facebook documents,if they will allow sharelinkcontent and sharedialog using both at a time

Comment: check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156776/sharing-content-with-facebook-sdk-4-0-ios